# Regex to get last name from a string

Tags: regex

So I have names in strings, and I need to extract the last name. The names come in these formats:

```
Mr. Firstname MI. Lastname (Designator)
```

and

```
Mr. Firstname (Nick) MI. Lastname (Designator)
```

The current regex I have checks for the existence of the "(" character, and gets the word character before it (LastName).

```
(/\\w+ ["("]/)
```

However, for names in the 2nd format, it returns the Firstname.  I need the regex to work backwards from the end of the string, find the first "(", and give me the word right before it.

Klendathu

Comment: A [necessary read](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). But, use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) it to the end of the string: [`\w+(?=\s*\([^)]+\)$)`](http://regex101.com/r/jM6oA4).

Comment: If your names are *really* always in this format, why not take the word after the second period (`\.`)?

Comment: Cause they don't always have a middle initial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Take my comment to heart about matching names (not regular) with "regular" expressions.*

---

However, you want to anchor your match to the end of the string with `$`.  I also threw the parenthesis logic into a lookahead, so it doesn't get included in the final match.

```
\w+(?=\s*\([^)]+\)$)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/iP3xV5)

Comment: Excellent read about names.  In this case, the names come formatted programmatically from data, and are always in one of 4 formats (the two noted above and the same formatting without the middle initial. It's only for a selenium IDE test to verify sorting.

Comment: Sounds good to me. May be worth doing something like `\S+` instead of `\w+`, so it can include names with `'`, etc.